# Replacing code with Grunt in multiple files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, scp

I have a .js file of which I need to make several different versions and upload them via SCP to different folders in the same location.

So, in my .js file there is something along the lines of:

```
var myObject = {
    someProp: 'value',
    otherProp: 'value'
}

(...continues with more code, functions, etc...)
```

The approach I was considering involves using [grunt-config](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-config), [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) and [grunt-scp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scp). So, I was thinking of having a bunch of different configs with the values I want to replace in my .js file, in order to create the several corresponding .js files, which would then be uploaded to different folders in the host via SCP.

What's confusing me is that I would like to do it all in one step, rather than running `grunt config --option` for each of my configuration options (there are quite a few of them).

At the moment, I already got the replacement working for one of the configs, but I was wondering if it is possible to do it all in sequence, like, replace first config in the file and SCP the output, then the next, etc...

Can anyone share some insight on how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Just noticed I might not have been as clear as I intended. The `grunt-scp` plugin needs to have its settings changed for each of the `grunt-config` options I'm dealing with.

The flow would be something along the lines of:

```
grunt.registerTask("myOption", ['config:first', 'replace', 'scp', 'config:second', 'replace', 'scp']); // and continues....
```

So far its correctly loading the first config and replacing in the file as intended, but I'm wondering how to use the config's settings with the `grunt-scp` plugin for each case.

This is due to the fact that the different files being generated on `grunt-replace`'s output must be `scp`'d to different places in the host.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess while registering task you can give it in a sequence. Something like this:   grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'injector:less', 
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
  ]);

Comment: @LukeP.Issac thanks for your reply. Yes, it does create a sequence, but I guess I wasn't explicit enough. I also need to change some of the settings for `grunt-scp` for each of the configs. I'll try to make it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering Multi Tasks in grunt. When a multi task is run, Grunt looks for a property of the same name in the Grunt configuration. Multi-tasks can have multiple configurations, defined using arbitrarily named "targets".